# Using XSLT with codebeside?

Tags: asp.net, xslt, codebeside

I find XSLT useful for a number of renderings (without too much logic builtin). When XSLT doesn't do the job, creating the functionality as an XSLT extension in .Net is a simple way to get the full power and functionality of the C#.

However - I've been unable to work out if XSLT extensions can be done in CodeBeside code ? I've only been using extensions in CodeBehind, but for various deployment reasons, I find CodeBeside easier to manage.

?

Answer (score 1):

CodeBeside is just a less-common term for partial classes, which otherwise work pretty much exactly the same as non-partial classes. Have you *tried* doing it and run into problems? If so, what are they precisely?